# How to migrate SQLYog server connections to another machine

Tags: sqlyog

I am changing my work computer, and need to move my sqlYog saved connections to the new machine. I do not remember the passwords, is there a way to move it?

Windows 7 machines.

Comment: Q&A created in order to make it easier for others to find this info.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are 2 ways:

1)  You will find sqlyog.ini in `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\SQLyog\sqlyog.ini` on recent Windows. So just copy it to new machine.

2) You can export/import your connection details. Exporting enables you to transfer connection details to other machines that you can later import into SQLyog. You can export/import connection from the `Tools->Export/Import Connection Details`

Refer [this](https://static.webyog.com/docs/SQLyog/Export_Import_Connections_SQLyog_MySQL_GUI.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Found in [this webpage](http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2013/02/23/how-to-export-sqlyog-saved-connections/):

Locate in `%appdata%` a file called `sqlyog.ini`.

Move this file to the new machine, and fire up sql yog.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Tools -> Export/Import Connection Details -> Export Connection Details` and select all the connections that you wish to export. Choose the directory where the file will be saved, then pick Export.

Use the same procedure to Import the connections (only this time use the Import option).

[image]